# Will pruning dead shoots off an arborvitae cause re-growth?

Tags: trees, pruning, evergreens

I planted 26 emerald arborvitae trees this summer. All but three are looking good. On each of those three, one of the shoots died. If I cut that part out, will the trees fill in?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will if those cedars are healthy. You should investigate to find out why the shoots died. Some possible causes with freshly planted cedars are:

- inadequate watering; new plants need a lot of water the first season
- too much watering: are they planted in a very wet area?
- spider mites or scale or leaf miner are common problems.  See [here](http://www.guelphlabservices.com/files/PDC/006Eastern%20White%20Cedar.pdf)
- physical damage during planting, deer

These answers are also related:

- [how to make cedars grow fast](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/9462/499)
- [are these cedars worth saving](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/11271/499)
- [how much damage can cedars recover from](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/11231/499)

Comment: Also check 'verticillium wilt'...

Comment: Also if a branch has no green, it will die.